# Record voice or convert it to a specific file type

Tags: android, audio, file-upload, mime-types

In my app i want to record the user voice and send it to the server .
the problem is server accept only this mime types :

```
 'audio' => array(
                'audio/basic',
                'audio/L24',
                'audio/mp4',
                'audio/mpeg',
                'audio/vnd.wave',
                'audio/ogg',
                'audio/opus',
                'audio/vnd.rn-realaudio',
                'audio/webm',
                'audio/mp3')
```

And apps in my device record sounds in other types like : `audio/3gpp` or `audio/amr`
How can i record voice or convert it to a specific file type ?

Comment: look at the mediarecorder, you will see that it also has `MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.WEBM`. would that not be sufficient?

Comment: it seems good ! i will google it , thx